# VS2015 Azure Remote Debugging Fails When Azure IP Restrictions are Applied

Tags: azure, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Once I apply IP restrictions on Azure app in the Networking section setting (see image below), then, even though I can connect to and browse the app through my web browser (which means the IP I'm coming from is valid), remote debug from vs2015 to my azure app fails to connect and gives the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named '-----.azurewebsites.net'. The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions, CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount, IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.MicrosoftWeb.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase.ConnectToServer(String site, String user, String password)
```

If I remove the IP restrictions, then I am able to remote debug, so I can't figure out why I get blocked for remote debug when the IP restrictions get applied (my IP is valid as I can browse the app). I hope someone has dealt with this issue and know how to resolve it; I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require setting up Azure VNET.

Azure Networking IP Restrictions:

[image]

Error Message:

[image]

Comment: Maybe with `IP restrictions` enabled, you should create some `inbound` rules in order to get remote debugging to work, this is the info from the docs `Visual Studio remote debugging User configurable 4016, 4018, 4020, 4022`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info